# Spork.prefork is loading app/models/*

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, spork

I can not figure out how to get spork not to load all of my app models.  Testing changes to my models is greatly slowed down as I am unable to use spork to help.  This is what I get when I debug what spork is loading:

```
    - Spork Diagnosis -
    -- Summary --
    app/models/account.rb
    app/models/admin.rb
    app/models/affiliate.rb
    app/models/app.rb
    app/models/application_server.rb
    app/models/domain_record.rb
    app/models/domain_zone.rb
    app/models/event.rb
    app/models/oid.rb
    app/models/user.rb
    config/application.rb
    config/boot.rb
    config/environment.rb
    config/environments/test.rb
    config/initializers/api_conversions.rb
    config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
    config/initializers/compass.rb
    config/initializers/devise.rb
    config/initializers/hoptoad.rb
    config/initializers/inflections.rb
    config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    config/initializers/rspec_generator.rb
    config/initializers/secret_token.rb
    config/initializers/session_store.rb
    config/routes.rb
    lib/application_server_api.rb
    lib/oid_helper.rb
    lib/soa_record.rb
    spec/spec_helper.rb



    -- Detail --



    --- app/models/account.rb ---
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.rc.7/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:54:in `load_model'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.rc.7/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in load_models'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.rc.7/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:16:in `each'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.rc.7/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:16:in `block in load_models'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/paths.rb:102:in `block in each'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/paths.rb:102:in `each'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/paths.rb:102:in `each'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.rc.7/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:15:in `load_models'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.rc.7/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in '
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:40:in `initialize'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `new'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `build'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `block in build'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `each'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `inject'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in `app'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35:in `block in '
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    config/environment.rb:8:in `'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    spec/spec_helper.rb:9:in `block in '
    /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3/lib/spork.rb:23:in `prefork'
    spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `'
```

**update: my spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

Spork.prefork do
  require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment')
  require 'rspec/rails'
end

Spork.each_run do
  # Hub::Application.reload_routes!
end

Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}
```

If I move `require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment')` out of the prefork, my models are not preloaded, but as you might expect it takes much longer to run my tests.

Any ideas on how to get spork to not load models on a Rails 3 app?  I have tried using spork 0.8.4, master branch, and currently 0.9.0.rc3.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can avoid having the models preloaded?

Comment: I don't see this behavior, using spork 0.8.4. Are you sure your prefork block is correct?

Comment: I updated the description with my pre_fork block in my spec_helper.rb

Comment: I'm still not seeing the problem. Maybe something going on in `config/environment'?

Comment: I generated a new empty Rails 3 app and my config/environment.rb and config/environments/test.rb do not differ with the new Rails 3 app's.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After much time spinning my wheels I finally have something that is acceptable:

```
Spork.prefork do
  require "rails/mongoid"
  Spork.trap_class_method(Rails::Mongoid, :load_models)

  # The following does not work correctly with Devise's routes that load the User model. 
  # Results in NameError unintitialized *
  # :reload_routes! triggers :devise_for which loads and caches the User class.
  # https://github.com/timcharper/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujutsu
  # require "rails/application"
  # Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application, :reload_routes!) 

  require 'factory_girl_rails'
  Spork.trap_class_method(Factory, :find_definitions)

  require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment')

end
```

The problem was mostly due to Rails::Mongoid#load_models.  After inspecting the debug output of spork and the backtrace of how things are loaded, some clues are provided as to what is loading the models.  This page goes into a bit more detail https://github.com/timcharper/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujutsu, but I do not find the :reload_routes! helping with Devise forcing the User class to be preloaded.

My specs are running much faster now.  If only I could get my User model to not be cached I would be in bliss, but until then, I shall be mostly satisfied.

Answer (score 8):

I have the following setup in both RSpec and Cucumber on Rails 3.1 and models are refreshing:

Set factory_girls_rails `require => false` in your Gemfile

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
```

Replace the Spork.prefork and Spork.each_run blocks with the following code.

```
if Spork.using_spork?

  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
  ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers

  Spork.prefork do

  end

  Spork.each_run do
    require 'factory_girl_rails'

    # reload all the models
    Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/*.rb"].each do |model|
      load model
    end

    # reload routes
    Rails.application.reload_routes!

  end

end
```

Comment: This is a really nice Spork setup template to follow! It will make Spork behave the way "you expected it to in the first place".  I encourage anybody reading this to follow this advice.

Comment: Wow I actually thought Spork does this by default and I was always surprised when it didn't reload my models. Thanks!

Comment: You can replace `YourApp::Application.reload_routes!` with `Rails.application.reload_routes` to make it more generic.

Comment: Good idea, i've changed the answer to use that method instead

Answer (score 7):

The following solution suggested [here](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/37#issuecomment-1984552) works for me.  It also reloads the User model.

```
# env.rb
Spork.each_run do
  require 'factory_girl_rails'
  # reload all the models
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/*.rb"].each do |model|
    load model
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for me (from http://my.rails-royce.org/2011/03/17/rspec-2-and-fixtures/)

```
Spork.prefork do
  require 'rails/application'
  Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application, :reload_routes!)
  Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!) 
  Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application, :eager_load!)
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  Rails.application.railties.all { |r| r.eager_load! }

  require 'rspec/rails'

  RSpec.configure do |config|
     ...
  end
end
```

Note that doing a "load model" in each_run is only a partial solution, this will re-evaluate the model code, but for instance after removing a model method it will still exist in memory until you restart Spork.